Prevent "shift + some letters" re-indenting the current line in neovim
I encountered a strange and annoying thing about neovim (w/o any additional setup and plugins).
In the insert mode, when I type some (but not all) capital letters, neovim re-indent the current line.
See the gif for details.
The gif is with a CMakeLists.txt file.
This happens even when I type in the middle of the line.

After quite some research, the closest thing I can get is indentkeys, which is claimed to trigger indentation and they are indentkeys=0{,0},0),0],:,0#,!^F,o,O,e,=ENDIF(,ENDFOREACH(,ENDMACRO(,ELSE(,ELSEIF(,ENDWH ILE( in my case.
Apparently, this is not the cause...
Will appreciate any clues...

That "vimrc" is anything but "basic". Anyway, do you have the same problem without -u ~/.vimrc?

thank you for your reply @romainl . Yes, neovim remains the same even w/o loading .vimrc. I also try vanilla vim (not neovim), it behaves the same when loading .vimrc, but doesn't otherwise.

Note that the vimrc is meant for Vim, not Neovim.
